# Server Error - Value Cannot Be Null - C# set;

Tags: c#

I am still new to C# and I have always been fine with declaring the `{get; set;}`, however per the SO solution **[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24122004/adding-additional-query-to-returnview)** I needed to do a manual `get` and now I run into an error where it says `value cannot be null`, after trying to do a "Filter by" on this page **[HERE](http://aawebapps.com/Starring)**.

The error then points to here in my debugger, due to me not having a `set`.

```
public string EmployeeNamesString
    {
        get { return string.Join(", ", this.employeeNames); } //System.ArgumentNullException
    }
```

I assume I should try something like `set { this.employeeNames = (someValue); }` but I am not sure what to set it as..

Could someone explain to me why this occuring, and how I may remedy this?

Thank you!

**ViewModel**

```
public class StarringViewModel
    {
        public int movieID { get; set; }
        public int roleID { get; set; }
        public int employeeID { get; set; }
        public string movieName { get; set; }
        public string movieDescription { get; set; }
        public DateTime? movieReleaseDate { get; set; }
        public string Role { get; set; }
        public string employeeName { get; set; }
        public DateTime employeeBirthdate { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<string> employeeNames { get; set; }
        public string EmployeeNamesString
        {
            get { return string.Join(", ", this.employeeNames); }
            set { this.employeeNames = someValue; } //attempt
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initially, your `employeeNames` collection is going to be `null`, so your call to `string.Join` will throw an `ArgumentNullException` if the collection has not been initialized.

```
public IEnumerable<string> employeeNames { get; set; }

public string EmployeeNamesString
{
    get { return string.Join(", ", this.employeeNames); }
}
```

One possibility is to initialize `employeeNames` in the constructor, so it's not null when you access `EmployeeNamesString`. You may also want to make the setter private, so nothing outside your class can make `employeeNames` null either.

```
public class StarringViewModel
{
    public StarringViewModel
    {
        employeeNames = new List<string>();
    }

    ...
    ...

    public IEnumerable<string> employeeNames { get; private set; }

    public string EmployeeNamesString
    {
        get { return string.Join(", ", employeeNames); }
    }
}
```

Comment: An alternative, albeit an unintuitive one, would be to use the null coalescing operator -- `get { return string.Join(", ", (employeeNames ?? (employeeNames = new List<string>())) } `

Comment: @DanielMann Eww... hiding a side-effect like that is inelegant, potentially confusing, and means you can't do useful things like checking if `employeeNames` was not set.  I'd rather write it as: `return employeeNames == null ? null : string.Join(", ", employeeNames);`

Comment: @Corey Agreed on all counts! Just throwing it out there.